# Mandelbrot very slow to refresh, any way to make it faster?

Tags: java, math, complex-numbers, fractals, mandelbrot

I've been working recently on a fractal generator, and have been specifically working on the Mandelbrot set. Unfortunately, zooming and moving seems to be very inneficient and takes quite a while to refresh. I am generating it every time I zoom, and I know this is probably not the most efficient way of doing this, and I can't seem to find code that uses another method that I understand. 
These are the following methods I use, the first being an intial generation, the second being a refresh method.

```
    private void genMandelbrot(Dimension size) {
    for(int x=0;x<size.width;x++) {
        for(int y=0;y<size.height;y++) {
            double moveX=globalx;
            double moveY=globalx;
            //zoom and x/y offset.
            double real = 1.5 * (x - size.width / 2) / (0.5 * zoom * size.width) + moveX;
            double imaginary=(y - size.height / 2) / (0.5 * zoom * size.height) + moveY;
            double newRe=0,newIm=0,oldRe=0,oldIm=0;

            int i;
            for(i=0;i<8000;i++) {
                oldRe = newRe;
                oldIm = newIm;
                newRe = oldRe * oldRe - oldIm * oldIm + real;
                newIm = 2 * oldRe * oldIm + imaginary;
                if((newRe * newRe + newIm * newIm) > 4) break;
            }

            Cell c = new Cell(Color.getHSBColor(i % 256, i % 255, 255 * ((i<20)? 1:0)), new Dimension(1,1), new Point(x,y));
            cells.add(c);
        }
    }
}
public void refreshMandelbrot(Dimension size) {
    for(Cell c : cells) {
            double moveX=globalx;
            double moveY=globalx;
            int x=c.x;
            int y=c.y;
            //zoom and x/y offset.
            double real = 1.5 * (x - size.width / 2) / (0.5 * zoom * size.width) + moveX;
            double imaginary=(y - size.height / 2) / (0.5 * zoom * size.height) + moveY;
            double newRe=0,newIm=0,oldRe=0,oldIm=0;

            int i;
            for(i=0;i<8000;i++) {
                oldRe = newRe;
                oldIm = newIm;
                newRe = oldRe * oldRe - oldIm * oldIm + real;
                newIm = 2 * oldRe * oldIm + imaginary;
                if((newRe * newRe + newIm * newIm) > 4) break;
            }

            cells.set(cells.indexOf(c), new Cell(Color.getHSBColor(i % 256, i % 255, 255 * ((i<20)? 1:0)), new Dimension(1,1), new Point(x,y)));
    }
    System.out.println("Set refreshed.");
}
```

Comment: Profile before try to optimize. Where is the most time spend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that `cells` is some kind of `List` implementation?

In that case, the most time of your refresh method is spent in this line:

`cells.set(cells.indexOf(c), new Cell(Color.getHSBColor(i % 256, i % 255, 255 * ((i<20)? 1:0)), new Dimension(1,1), new Point(x,y)));`

More precisely in `cells.indexOf(c)`, where the entire list is iterated to find the correct index of `c`.

Since you are just changing the colour of each cell, the easiest fix is to change the colour of the cell you are currently working with. I don't know the actual implementation of your `Cell` class, but if it had a method `setColor(...)`, you could replace the above line with

`c.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(i % 256, i % 255, 255 * ((i<20)? 1:0)));`

This reduces the runtime of the `refreshMandelbrot` method to the same as for the `genMandelbrot` method.

I don't know the purpose of the `Cell` class, but if you are only using it as a wrapper for a colour, you might gain some more performance if you store the computed colours for each pixel in a two-dimensional array or write directly to a `Graphics` or `Raster` object instead of handling a flat list of cell wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to subdivide the fractal and compute the less interesting tiles less intense. 8000 repetiton is a lot. You can also simplify the calculation a bit.